# What is the best way to play "*.mp3" files in java?

Tags: java, mp3, jmf, mplayer, vlcj

Is there an interface to VLC or MPlayer which I can use?
I simply want an interface (Servlet -> Java) which is able to play songs on a linux machine.

Comment: Do you want the songs to be played on the server or streamed to the client's web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is what you want, [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html)

Answer (score 1):

VLC jas [Java bindings](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/). Here's a sample from the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/Usage):

```
String[] libvlcArgs = {...add options here...};
MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(libvlcArgs);
FullScreenStrategy fullScreenStrategy = new DefaultFullScreenStrategy(mainFrame);
EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaPlayer(fullScreenStrategy);
String[] standardMediaOptions = {"video-filter=logo", "logo-file=vlcj-logo.png", "logo-opacity=25"}; 
mediaPlayer.setStandardMediaOptions(standardMediaOptions);
mediaPlayer.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {...add implementation here...});
Canvas videoSurface = new Canvas();
mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);
String mediaPath = "/path/to/some/movie.mpg";
String[] mediaOptions = {};
mediaPlayer.playMedia(mediaPath, mediaOptions);
// Do some interesting things in the application
...
mediaPlayer.release();
mediaPlayerFactory.release();
```

Answer (score 1):

This task does not require JMF. Just add the mp3plugin.jar of the JMF into the run-time class path of the app. and Java sound will then be able to read and play MP3s.

You might also look at [Java Bindings for VideoLAN](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/).

Either way, it will require an applet or JWS launched application.